# How To remove an item from Login Items using shell script

Tags: macos, nsarray, shell

In Mac, 
I want to remove an application from the login items using Shell script.

I tried following code, but didn't work..

```
   defaults write loginwindow  AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary -array-remove path "/Applications/myApp.app"
```

But it is giving error "Unexpected argument -path; leaving defaults unchanged"

Regards,
Dhanaraj

Answer (score 1):

`-array-remove` does not exist… I solved this issue this way:

```
ln=`/usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Preferences/loginwindow AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary | grep "Path =" | sed -n '/myApp.app/='`
if [ "$ln" != "" ]
then
    echo $ln | /usr/bin/sort -nr | while read k
    do
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary:$(($k-1)) dict" /Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist
    done
fi
```

Comment: !? What's with ```fi```? Is that an alternate to ```End if```?